# How to best defend against someone with a knife while unarmed?

Tags: weapons, self-defense, fight

My main character is experienced at fist fighting, though is self taught. At 18, he travels to a city in an industrial era time period (circa 1820 - 1850) to find work, but upon arriving there, is foolishly misled by people seeking to mug him. He was going to end up facing a whole street gang, but went in the wrong direction, and is faced with only one gang member, who is armed with a knife.

What are some considerations that my character should use to defend himself until help arrives?

Comment: One question per post. Please don't edit your post to ask another question based on answers; it make them obsolete and is not suited to SO format.

Comment: This follows as a worldbuilding problem, not simple story telling?

Comment: @frеdsbend  This is a question about fighting tactics to help influence my storytelling.

Comment: My teacher's advice was if you go unarmed into a knife fight.  Expect to get cut.  Even with Enough skill to win, expect to get cut.

Answer (score 8):

Appears that your protagonist doesn't have any fancy martial arts skills or experience in disarming armed foes, so...

Simplest and probably safest option is to run, the only consideration being "can this gang member run faster (or for longer) than me?"

Next option would be to fortuitously find a club-shaped piece of timber on the side of the road and 'defend' himself by attempting to bludgeon the gang member. The considerations there being "is this chunk of timber too clumsy to wield efficiently?" and "is it possible that the gang-member will just back off if approached by a maniac waving a large (nail-studded?) chunk of wood?"

Another option might be to pick up a handy cobble-stone and throw it at the assailant's face or groin. Rinse and repeat if necessary. Considerations are "is my aim good enough?", "are there enough rocks nearby?", "is there too much risk that the gang-member will stab me while I am bending down to pick up a rock?"

How about trying to talk the gang-member down? Claim that they are actually an unrecognised member of the gang themselves, or the assailant's long-lost half brother, or claim that they actually *do* have "Special Forces" skills and will snap every bone in the assailant's body if they don't immediately back off.

Comment: Running also requires somewhere to run to.  In a strange city, the risk of being cornered by running somewhere you don't know is very high.

Answer (score 5):

Knives are tricky. They're small, twisty, and can easily kill you even if you beat up the wielder. If you can, avoid fighting them. Turning tail and running is a good idea. Giving them your wallet is another. Most good martial arts places will say this- fights can have life long consequences, don't get in street brawls if you can avoid it.

Also, if you do have to kill them, it looks good if you run first. It's hard for them to claim self defence if they chased you down.

If, because of pride, lack of options, or whatever they're gonna fight, the first step is trying to get something between you and the knife wielder. Clothes, a bin, a trash bag, whatever. Shove it into their face, in between yourself and the knife. Let the knife tear apart that, rather than your face. Hit them repeatedly with it till they go down, and run before their buddies come.

Being good at fist fighting isn't that helpful. While you have a boxing match with them they can carve a noughts and crosses on your chest. Unless you have a punch like Mike Tyson and can one shot them, better to avoid it.

Comment: Deluding the foe into thinking you are too frightened to fight and then surprising them with the punch is a possibility.  But only if you think you can incapacitate them.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot find it but a Navy Seal just made a video on this. The question posed to him was what would he do if someone pulled a knife on him outside of combat.  His answer was to run. If you are not defending family or something similar and you have a path to escape, then it is foolish to be in a combat situation for no reason. If you have two people in a knife fight both are going to get hurt pretty bad even if both are experts. It is important to remember that testosterone is not an intelligence-enhancing drug.

Answer (score 2):

**John Wick style?**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpl-s-HrcNw

[image: keanu removes belt]

Keanu qua Wick uses his belt to effectively fight these 2 knife-wielding guys.  A very sweet scene.

Unlike the nattily dressed Keanu your protagonist wears sweat pants but he could use those instead of the belt.  Also unfortunate that he always goes commando.  His opponent will probably be surprised.  But no-one will be able to say you were just copying John Wick.

Comment: That's all well and good if you are either ungodly skilled at martial arts, or wear a very thick plot armor. Wouldn't recommend otherwise. Probability is, you let go of one end of the belt on the first strike and get stabbed, die.

Answer (score 2):

Stella the gang member is smaller than Jim the protagonist but she has a knife. So Jim turns around to run away, just as Stella lunges at him. The knife sticks in his backpack and is torn out of her hand as he turns suddenly. The knife clatters to the ground putting Jim between Stella and the knife. Then he can fight her with his fists.

**Consideration:** The safest option is probably still to run -- in case Stella's friends arrive or she pulls out a second knife.

Answer (score 2):

## De-escalate, distract, fight dirty, get injured, run away

A knife is a *force-multiplier*. This means that if one has it,
and the other does not, it is a *very* unfair fight.

[Here is a video](https://youtu.be/GBBahcNMSDI) of someone that is an *expert* in bare-hand fighting, trying to defend himself against someone with a knife.

Result?

Very(!) badly for the bare-hand fighter, especially when the knife-weilder starts slashing.

---

Hence, if you want any kind of realism, your protagonist will do everything they can to *avoid* getting into an actual fight. The most important tactic is to *de-escalate*.

If your protagonist cannot de-escalate, next they will try to keep their distance, and avoid getting into reach of the knife-wielder.

Finally, they will run away.

If you are hell-bent on writing an actual fight, you will have to let one or more of the following happen: your protagonist will...

- Fight very dirty
- Get lucky
- Get injured
- Disentangle themselves from the fracas and run away
- Any combination of the above

---

In short, you will never bet on *winning* against a knife-weilder in an actual fight. Best is to avoid the fight all-together, and if that do not work, disengage as quickly as possible and run away.

Comment: Thank you, this one was very helpful, especially the video. Seeing how difficult it is for a well trained marital arts fighter to defend against a knife, I think I might have some justification for the street gang member losing his weapon - as I find it hard to believe that they would want to get into a fist fight when it is so much easier to threaten people with a knife.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume your character is incapable of running safely. This is the absolute best option in this situation. No misguided honor or confidence should ever lead someone to get into this fight.

"experienced at fist fighting"
This leads me to assume your character is an athlete of sorts. So. Whatever I suggest will be more applicable to your character than the average person.

**Stay out of reach.**

Pretty simple. Will a knife has more reach than a fist, it is still a melee weapon that is quite short. So. Your character should keep moving out of reach of the knife. They are fast but again your guy is faster and more trained. This is combined with what I will suggest below.

**Grab a weapon or a defense**

Is there a lead pip there? Great. Does he carry a metal water bottle? Awesome. Heck.  A brick can crush a skull. The idea is to even the playing field and get as many advantages as possible.

Heck. In actual historical manuals they would advice to take off your big heavy cloak and wrap it around the arm to defend yourself, even against swords.
So. If they got a thick winter coat then they can do that. Or a heavy bag. Or keeping a bicycle between them and the attacker. Again just any advantage they can.

**Grappling**

I will assume this is probably what you are looking for. And again we are working with someone who is somewhat trained. Especially speed and basic body mechanics.
And facing a life or death situation.

Simply go for the knife, control the arm with both hands, put his body behind the arm. Wait for a stab then duck, and from there controlling the arm with both hands. Dancing away from a cut and stab then hitting back...etc

Grappling with anyone is dangerous. They might get cut. Or they might disarm the person. Just be prepared for some serious fighting. The idea is that, again, they have no choice. Adrenaline will be pumping, in both people actually, and they might not even notice cuts or hits.

That why it's important for your character to hold on to that arm/wrist and deal with the knife. There is not loading and earlier save, this is death.

While we are on grappling anything goes. Thump in the eye, a hit to the neck, kick to the balls, kick in the stomach, dashing the head against a wall...etc. Your guy should just want to get out of this alive and the only way is to disarm the other person and make sure they are no longer a danger. Dead or unconscious.

**Not all cuts are lethal, but avoid stabs**

I can't stress enough how deadly knife fights are. But I'm sure we all can agree on that fighting is better than being stabbed to death in silence.

However there was some study I heard about, long ago sorry, that said that in general there was a number of cuts that you can take and survive. I think it was 6.
Something like that. Of course this does not include a stab to the heart or cutting the jugular or something like that.

The body is an incredible machine and many cuts are not instantly lethal. Your guy can take a couple in non lethal place. The attack is unlikely to be a train assassin, that simply moves a knife in 1 motion to kill your character.

Perhaps the aggressor cuts your character a shallow cut to frighten them, or in general a cut that is not lethal. Again they are not a trained professional.

**Delay and run**

Again I suggest running. But if they can't run right away, maybe they can create an opportunity to run?

I think this is the best option as it shows they are stubborn and willing to fight and defend themselves, but he is no fool and knows what is the best option for the situation

Comment: Grappling is a bad idea when knife fighting. Knives are small, very agile weapons. You can't stop them slicing you whilst you try to grapple their arm, and it's often easy to slip out of a grapple and stabby stabby.